# Hibernate custom ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

Is there a way to create my own Hibernate ExceptionMapper rather than use ExceptionMapperStandardImpl?  I am getting an error in my logs and I would like to get the stacktrace, but the standard impl only prints out the message of the exception.

Here is the error I'm getting

> [io-9010-exec-17] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        :
>   HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned
>   unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected:
>   1]

I have tried adding logging to all my controller endpoints, but can't seem to find where this exception is coming from.  I know what the exception means (one db object is being updated by multiple things at the same time,) but I can't track down the code path where this is occurring.

I'm not getting any other logging along with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to debug locally you could breakpoint the ExceptionMapperStandardImpl class or override it in your implementation by [copy-pasting from the hibernate source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.java) into a org.hibernate.internal package in your source